# Entity Framework Core: combined primary key through navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, foreign-keys, composite-primary-key, ef-fluent-api

Given are the following classes:

```
public class Person{
    public int ID { get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public List<Parentship> parentChildRelations { get; set; }
}

public class Parentship{
    public Person Parent { get; set; }
    public Person Child { get; set; }
    public string RelationshipType { get; set; }
    public Datetime date { get; set; }
```

With Entity Framework Core (Code First), I'd like to map this to the following tables:

table Person:

| ColumnName | DataType | Primary Key | Foreign Key |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID | int | YES | NO |
| Name | varchar(max) | NO | NO |

table Parentship:

| ColumnName | DataType | Primary Key | Foreign Key |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ParentID | int | YES | YES |
| ChildID | int | YES | YES |
| Type | int | NO | NO |
| Date | datetime | NO | NO |

so that the table `Parentship` has a composite primary key (`ParentID`, `ChildID`), where these columns themselves are foreign keys to the table `Person`.

I tried something like this, which doesn't work as it gives the following error message in the PM Console: "The property 'Parentship.Parent' is of type 'Person' which is not supported by the current database provider. Either change the property CLR type, or ignore the property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.".
Anyone got any idea how to resolve this trough Fluent API?

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Parentship>()
    .HasKey(p => new { ParentID = p.Parent.ID, ChildID = p.Child.ID });
```

Comment: @GertArnold: see edit.

Answer (score -2):

Please try adding an index value and set it as non-clustered index

```
entity.HasIndex(p => new { p.Parent.ID, p.Child.ID})
                    .HasName("some_name_for_index")
                    .ForSqlServerIsClustered(false);
```

Comment: Please test code before posting. This is invalid.